# Limit on join query using between

Tags: mysql, performance, time-series

I am trying to filter some results indexed by a timestamp using another set of results that define valid timestamp periods.

**Current query:**

```
SELECT Measurements.moment AS "moment",
       Measurements.actualValue,
       start,
       stop
FROM Measurements
       INNER JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(@previousValue <> M.actualValue AND @previousResource = M.resourceId, 1) AS "changed",
                          (COALESCE(@previousMoment, ?)) AS "start",
                          M.moment AS "stop",
                          @previousValue AS "actualValue",
                          M.resourceId,
                          @previousMoment := moment,
                          @previousValue := M.actualValue,
                          @previousResource := M.resourceId
                   FROM Measurements `M`
                          INNER JOIN (SELECT @previousValue := NULL, @previousResource := NULL, @previousMoment := NULL) `d`
                   WHERE (M.moment BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND
                         (M.actualValue > ?)
                   ORDER BY M.resourceId ASC, M.moment ASC) `changes` ON Measurements.moment BETWEEN changes.start AND changes.stop
WHERE (Measurements.resourceId = 1) AND
      (Measurements.moment BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND
      (changes.changed)
ORDER BY Measurements.moment ASC;
```

`resourceId, moment` is already an index.
Since these are actually timeseries data, is there any way to limit the join on just 1 match to improve performance?

**Sample data**

```
+-------------+---------------------+------------+
| actualValue | moment              | resourceId |
+-------------+---------------------+------------+
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:50:25 |        1   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:52:35 |        1   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:52:44 |        2   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:52:54 |        1   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:53:03 |        1   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:53:13 |        2   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:53:22 |        1   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:54:32 |        1   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:55:41 |        1   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:56:51 |        1   |
+-------------+---------------------+------------+
```

**Expected output**: All measurements with `resourceId=1` where `resourceId=2` had a measurement in that same minute (in an advanced version, the minute can be dynamic).

```
+-------------+---------------------+------------+
| actualValue | moment              | resourceId |
+-------------+---------------------+------------+
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:52:35 |        1   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:52:54 |        1   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:53:03 |        1   |
|        0.01 | 2018-09-26 07:53:22 |        1   |
+-------------+---------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Without minimal relevant sample data, and expected output, it is hard to fathom what you are asking for.

Comment: I added some data to show structure. What I am trying to achieve is probably typical in TSDBs, but I am trying to reproduce it in MySQL.

Comment: You possibly need [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html). It is hard to figure out without the problem context and expected output (given your sample data)

Comment: I have tried adding it as a correlated subquery but the performance does not improve. It seems that the entire second table is scanned for each row join, while it could stop on the first match.

Comment: Well I dont think that general RDBMS are designed to stop scanning on finding first match in a join. I have also wanted a similar thing in past many times, but could not find any solution

Comment: Yes, the inner query is executed first, since it's independent. When it finishes, the outer one is executed. Let me take a look.

Comment: What version of MySQL? I will assume 8.x for now.

Comment: I am using MariaDB 10.2

Comment: Eh?  You can add `LIMIT 1` to the _end_ of the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using table unpivoting:

```
SELECT moment, value
FROM (SELECT IF(resourceId = ? AND @previousValue = 0, NULL, actualValue)       AS value,
             measurements.moment,
             resourceId,
             @previousValue := IF(resourceId <> ?, actualValue, @previousValue) AS enabled
      FROM (SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT moment,
                         Measurements.actualValue,
                         Measurements.resourceId AS resourceId
                  FROM Measurements
                  WHERE Measurements.resourceId = ?
                    AND moment BETWEEN ? AND ?
                  UNION (SELECT start,
                                periods.actualValue AS actualValue,
                                resourceId
                         FROM (SELECT COALESCE(@previousValue <> M3.actualValue,                                            1)                                                              AS "changed",
                                      (COALESCE(@previousMoment, ?))                                           AS "start",
                                      @previousMoment := M3.moment                                             AS "stop",
                                      COALESCE(@previousValue, IF(M3.actualValue = 1, 0, 1)) AS "actualValue",
                                      M3.resourceId                                                            AS resourceId,
                                      @previousValue := M3.actualValue
                               FROM Measurements `M3`
                                      INNER JOIN (SELECT @previousValue := NULL,
                                                         @previousMoment := NULL) `d`
                               WHERE (M3.moment BETWEEN ? AND ?)
                               ORDER BY M3.resourceId ASC, M3.moment ASC) AS periods
                         WHERE periods.changed)) AS measurements
            ORDER BY moment ASC) AS measurements
             INNER JOIN (SELECT @previousValue := NULL) `k`) AS mixed
WHERE value IS NOT NULL
  AND resourceId = ?;
```

This runs essentially runs table once per select, running ~40k x ~4k rows in 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an independent subquery (this case) then it's executed entirely before the outer query. In your case this could be potentially massive, and probably most of the rows are not really neeeded.

If you rephrase the query using an inner `JOIN` then the secondary access to the table will be filtered out immediately, avoiding the need for a full scan of the table.

Try the following query:

```
select 
    m.moment,
    m.actualValue,
    c.moment as start,
    timestampadd(minute, 1, c.moment) as stop
  from Measurements m
  join Measurements c on m.moment
    between c.moment and timestampadd(minute, 1, c.moment)
  where m.resourceId = 1
    and c.resourceId = 2
    and m.moment between ? and ?
  order by m.moment
```

Comment: That would not work because of the structure of my `c` table. It selects ranges from Measurements and returns a `start, stop` pair per row. If I make that subquery external, then it loses its functionality. Your solution is a good point, but I would have to change the way I calculate `start, stop` pairs.

Comment: @MikeDrakoulelis "...and returns a start, stop pair per row." -- yes, it does, the same way my query does on alias "c", including the same functionality. However it only does it for relevant pairs, not the whole table. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, please check my updated query, which provides the entire subquery. I did not provide it at the first place because it might be confusing. However, it does have good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Composite Index needed:

```
Measurements:  INDEX(resourceId, moment)  -- in this order
```

You may want `AND  (Measurements.moment BETWEEN ? AND ?)` in the subquery

In a "derived table" (the subquery you have), the Optimizer is free to ignore the `ORDER BY`.  If, however, you add a `LIMIT`, the `ORDER BY` will be honored.

Comment: I do have an index like this. It usually helps but here the join is not done using the same resourceId thus it cannot be used. I tried adding the inner query an `M3.moment BETWEEN ? AND ?` since that's the related table, but the performance increase was not big enough. Running the nested query on itself takes ~100ms, so I do no think that's doing the performance hit, rather the join using join buffer.

Comment: I am not sure if limit can be applied, since I do not want to limit the results.

Comment: @MikeDrakoulelis - Sorry, I was misinterpreting your "limit the join on just 1 match".